# How do I detect External GPU (eGPU) connection and disconnection on macOS?

Tags: macos, gpu, metal, iokit

I'd like to write a macOS app which detects when you disconnect an external GPU via the `Disconnect "GPU Name"` Menu Extra and then takes some action.

- What API do I use to detect the presence of the GPU?
- Can I get notifications when the GPU is disconnected and subsequently plugged in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Apple's [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal?language=objc) [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/choosing_gpus_on_mac/handling_external_gpu_additions_and_removals?language=objc#2957300):

> ### Register for External GPU Notifications
>
> Call the [`MTLCopyAllDevicesWithObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/2869731-mtlcopyalldeviceswithobserver?language=objc) function to get a list
>   of all the Metal devices available to a system and register an
>   observer that's called whenever this list changes (or may change due
>   to a safe disconnect request).
>
> ```
> id <NSObject> deviceObserver  = nil;
> NSArray<id<MTLDevice>> *deviceList = nil;
> deviceList = MTLCopyAllDevicesWithObserver(&deviceObserver,
>                                            ^(id<MTLDevice> device, MTLDeviceNotificationName name) {
>                                                [self handleExternalGPUEventsForDevice:device notification:name];
>                                            });
> _deviceObserver = deviceObserver;
> _deviceList = deviceList;
> ```
>
> To deregister the observer, call the [`MTLRemoveDeviceObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/2869724-mtlremovedeviceobserver?language=objc)
>   function.
>
> ### Respond to External GPU Notifications
>
> Metal notifies your app about these external GPU events:
>
> - [`MTLDeviceWasAddedNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevicewasaddednotification?language=objc). Metal posts this notification when an external GPU is added to the system. Evaluate the
>     updated list of devices and consider using the new addition.
> - [`MTLDeviceRemovalRequestedNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldeviceremovalrequestednotification?language=objc). Metal posts this notification when the user initiates a safe disconnect request for an
>     external GPU. Your app has approximately one second to migrate work
>     off the device and remove all references to it. If your app fails to
>     do so, macOS notifies the user that your app is blocking the safe
>     disconnect request.
> - [`MTLDeviceWasRemovedNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevicewasremovednotification?language=objc). Metal posts this notification when an external GPU is removed from the system and your
>     app still has references to that device. If the user safely
>     disconnected an external GPU, Metal posts this notification after it
>     posts a [`MTLDeviceRemovalRequestedNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldeviceremovalrequestednotification?language=objc) notification. If
>     the user unexpectedly disconnected an external GPU, Metal posts this
>     notification without first posting a
>     [`MTLDeviceRemovalRequestedNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldeviceremovalrequestednotification?language=objc) notification. After an
>     external GPU is removed, any command buffers queued for the device are
>     completed with an error, and any new API calls that reference the
>     device fail with an error.
>
> Set up a method to respond to the notifications, and pass this method
>   to the handler parameter of the [`MTLCopyAllDevicesWithObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/2869731-mtlcopyalldeviceswithobserver?language=objc)
>   function.
>
> ```
> - (void)handleExternalGPUEventsForDevice:(id<MTLDevice>)device notification:(MTLDeviceNotificationName)notification
> {
>     if (notification == MTLDeviceWasAddedNotification) {  }
>     else if (notification == MTLDeviceRemovalRequestedNotification) {  }
>     else if (notification == MTLDeviceWasRemovedNotification) {  }
> }
> ```

Comment: Does windows have something like this? I can't find anything online. I wanted to make an app that hotswaps video game config so I can adjust graphics settings for each gpu based on it's capabilities.